# How can I order my join results by count?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables `shipments` and `support_tickets`, common element in 2 tables is `tracking_id`. I want to count the provider name base on conditions from support_tickets table.  I tried this:

### MySQL query:

```
SELECT provider,count(provider) as pen_tick_iss 
from shipments 
inner join support_tickets on shipments.tracking_id=support_tickets.tracking_id 
where support_tickets.issue_status = 'Pending'  
AND support_tickets.ticket_flag = '1' 
AND support_tickets.multi_loc_pickup = '0' 
AND support_tickets.status = 'Active'  
group BY provider ORDER BY count(provider) DESC
```

### `shipments`   table

```
id  tracking_id provider    created_date
1   1231232332  fedex   01-09-2017
2   3435435345  fedex   02-09-2017
3   56564564    aramex  03-09-2017
4   535456456   fedex   04-09-2017
5   4565465 delhivery   05-09-2017
6   45656456    fedex   06-09-2017
7   3453453534  fedex   07-09-2017
8   6856865856  delhivery   08-09-2017
9   99923423432 fedex   09-09-2017
10  99923434    delhivery   10-09-2017
11  343343423   aramex  11-09-2017
12  93458345    aramex  12-09-2017
13  435345345   delhivery   13-09-2017
14  3454462136  fedex   14-09-2017
15  989798723   delhivery   15-09-2017
```

### `support_tickets` table

```
id  tracking_id issue_status    status  ticket_flag created_date
1   1231232332  pending Active  1   01-09-2017
2   3435435345  pending Active  1   11-09-2017
3   56564564    pending Active  1   11-09-2017
4   535456456   fixed   Active      15-09-2017
5   4565465 pending Deleted 1   15-09-2017
6   45656456    pending Active  1   15-09-2017
7   3453453534  fixed   Active      16-09-2017
8   6856865856  fixed   Active      17-09-2017
9   99923423432 pending Active  0   18-09-2017
10  99923434    pending Active  0   19-09-2017
11  343343423   pending Deleted 1   20-09-2017
12  93458345    fixed   Active      21-09-2017
13  435345345   pending Active  1   22-09-2017
14  3454462136  pending Active  1   23-09-2017
15  989798723   fixed   Active      24-09-2017
```

Comment: shipments table   : tracking_id |      provider    |      created_date

Comment: add your expected result and current result

Comment: support_tickets : tracking_id |   issue_status |   status   |    ticket_flag |    created_date

Comment: in `support_tickets` table `issues_status` is `pending` but in query `support_tickets.issue_status = 'Pending' ` with capital letter with `P` change it to `p`.

Comment: expected result               fedex -   4
delhivery   -  2
aramex   -  2

Comment: try above solution , change capital `P` to small letter `p`. in query

Comment: #chirag  that is corrected.   in current output i am getting the total count of each provider wise .                fedex -  7   delhivery  -  5    aramex  -  3

Comment: can you edit your answer and add what you got from your query?

Comment: #Gagantous                  current output i am getting the total count of each provider wise                  fedex - 7 delhivery - 5 aramex - 3

Comment: can anyone help me on this issue